# reading csv files in loop

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to read all csv files in directory in loop and need to append one row in each file.
Using below code -

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($file_path);

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        $j=0;
        if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            $file = "D:/2929/".$fileinfo->getFilename();
            $total_a = 0;
            $total_b = 0;
            $total_c = 0;
            $total_d = 0;

            $generated_file = fopen($file, "r");
            while(($new_row = fgetcsv($generated_file, 0, ",")) != false)
            {
                $total_a += $new_row[7];
                $total_b += $new_row[8];
                $total_c += $new_row[9];
                $total_d += $new_row[10];
            }

                $write_file = fopen($file, "a");

                fputcsv($write_file, array('Total', '', '', '', '', '', '',$total_a,$total_b,$total_c,$total_d));
                fclose($write_file);


        }
    }
```

Last row need to append is Total with values of columns. But, when I run this, it running in infinite loop.
Not getting, what's went wrong here.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you determine which line causes the loop? Is it possible that you dump the appended CSV file and read it in again?

Comment: Not sure, which line causes the loop, but if I open file in write mode, then it works, but existing data gets blank, and just added single Total row.

Comment: So, you probably should add some logging to see why there is an infinite loop. Eg output `$fileinfo->getFilename()` after entering the loop

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, except that are you opening the file twice (once readonly, once writeonly) and that you do not close the `$generated_file`handler. Why don't you just use `fopen($file, "a+");`